# how to get multiple opco codes at a time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
OpCo_code = spark.sql(f""" 
  SELECT
    OPCOCode 
  FROM
    delta. / {SALES_ORG_REFERENCE_OBJECT} 
  WHERE
    ForecastUnitCode = "{SalesOrg_row['ProductKeyCode']}" 
    AND SalesOrganisationCode = "{SalesOrg_row['SalesOrganisationCode']}" 
    AND RegionID = "{SalesOrg_row['RegionID']}" """).collect()[0][0]
```

**print(OpCo_code)**

```
result :HP
```

but it having multiple OPCOCode  like HP,IC,FD,UF
it getting single OPCOCode
some one help here

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting only first element from list you are getting single value.

Below code will give complete list:

```
out = spark.sql("sql query")

out.rdd.map(lambda r: r.OPCOCode).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OpCo_code = spark.sql(f""" 
SELECT OPCOCode 
FROM delta.`/{SALES_ORG_REFERENCE_OBJECT}` 
                  WHERE ForecastUnitCode="{SalesOrg_row['ProductKeyCode']}" AND SalesOrganisationCode = "{SalesOrg_row['SalesOrganisationCode']}"   AND RegionID ="{SalesOrg_row['RegionID']}" """)

OpCo_code.rdd.map(lambda r: r.OPCOCode).collect()
```

output: `['HP', 'HP', 'HP', 'HP']`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).